# Django Tutorials part 3: Error while creating view and template

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, jinja2

I started learn Django (1.11) and I follow [Django Tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/). In this part I should create dynamic view (index method) with template. But after I created template

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

and index view that uses template

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

from .models import Question


    def index(request):
        latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
        template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
        context = {
            'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

I've go an Error:
 *NameError at /polls/
*global name 'latest_question_list' is not defined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
...

from django.template import loader

from .models import Question

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list, }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

`from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request,'polls/index.html',context)`